# Email HTML: Outlook adding extra pixel

Tags: html, email, html-email

Outlook is adding an extra pixel on the right to my HTML email. Any idea on how to fix this? from what I read on the net `border-collapse: collapse !important;` should of fixed it but its not. [Outlook HTML Tricks/Tips](http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C6/tips_and_tricks_outlook_07-13)

```
<tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">
<td width="15" valign="top" style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;" align="left"> </td>
<td style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; margin: 0; padding: 0;" align="left" valign="top">

<table class="container" width="580" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: inherit; min-width:580px; width: 580px; background: #fff; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; border-left: 1px solid #d2d2d2; border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2; border-right: 1px solid #d2d2d2;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to give this a shot.

```
<style>
    table { border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;}
    table td {border-collapse: collapse;}
</style>

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="15" valign="top" style="color:#222222;font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;font-size: 14px;"></td>
        <td style="color: #222222; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;font-size: 14px;">
            <table class="container" width="580" border="1" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="580" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="min-width:580px;border-color:#d2d2d2;border-top:none;">
                <tr><td></td></tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;"` on your image tag. The missing `display:block;` is probably the cause. Otherwise it could be because your image is set to the same width as your table/td, try decreasing it by 2px as the 1px border may be pushing it wider.

Besides that, you have a lot of unnecessary code in there. Try this instead:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border:1px solid #d2d2d2;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/600x100" width="100%" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" style="font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size:20px; padding:5%;">
      Text here<br>
      ...
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is fluid, so it will resize to the container or window/screen (whatever is smaller). On a side note, with all the hyphens code you have in there, I'm guessing you want to control the break points on large bodies of text within a fluid layout. Try using `&nbsp;` between the words. Something like:

```
This sentence will have no orphan words and will split&nbsp;into&nbsp;nice blocks&nbsp;of&nbsp;text.
```

There I am forcing the page break between 'nice' and 'block', should the width cause it to overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Try empty `<td>` `font-size:0; line-height: 0;` and try there `line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px;` which must.

Comment: still taking away a pixel